# Get parameters of fitted model of KernelRidge class scikit learn library

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use KernelRidge class of scikit_learn library to fit nonlinear regression model on my data. But I am getting confused how I can do that.

```
 from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
 import numpy as np
 n_samples, n_features = 20,1
 rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
 y = rng.randn(n_samples)
 X = rng.randn(n_samples, n_features)
 Krr = KernelRidge(alpha=1.0, kernel='linear',degree = 4)
 Krr.fit(X, y)
```

I am expecting 5 coefficients to be set for this model, how can I get them?

The above code will transform 1-D data to 4-D space and fit the model to the data.  I think it should find best c0,c1,c2,c3,c4 according to the training data. My question is how can I access c0,c1,c2,c3,c4?

EDIT:

I made a mistake in above my code here, kernel parameter should be "polynomial" instead of "linear" in line 7.

```
  Krr = KernelRidge(alpha=1.0, kernel='polynomial',degree = 4)
```

But my question is same as before.

Comment: Maybe _get_params() should be documented

Comment: no this function will return all parameters I had set for KernelRidge class once I define it.

Answer (score 2):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge.html#sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge

dual_coef_ : array, shape = [n_features] or [n_targets, n_features]

so

```
Krr.dual_coef_
```

should do it.

EDIT:

Ok, so dual_coef_ is the coefficient in the Kernel space. For a linear kernel, the Kernel, K(X,X') is X.T *X . So this is an NxN matrix, hence the number of coefficients equal to the the dimension of y.

there are 3 equations we need to understand,

[image]

The first is the standard ridge regression weight estimation.
The second is the partially kernalised version, with the relation linking the two being the third equation.

dual_coef_ returns the alpha of equation 2. Therefore to have the weight vector in the 'normal' space, rather than the kernel space as it is returned, you need to do X.T * Krr.dual_coef_

We can check this is correct because KRR and Ridge Regression are the same if the kernel is linear.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge


rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = 5 * rng.rand(100, 1)
y = np.sin(X).ravel()

Krr = KernelRidge(alpha=1.0, kernel='linear', coef0=0)
R = Ridge(alpha=1.0,fit_intercept=False)
Krr.fit(X, y)
R.fit(X, y)
print np.dot(X.transpose(),Krr.dual_coef_)
print R.coef_
```

I see this to output:

```
[-0.03997686]
[-0.03997686]
```

Will show they are equivalent (you have to change the intercept options as the defaults differ between the models).

As the degree parameter is ignored, as I mentioned in the comments, the coefficient should be 1x1 in this case (as it is).

If you want to know exactly what a particular model returns, I recommend looking at the source code on github, which I think is the only way to gain a deeper understanding of how this stuff works. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/kernel_ridge.py

Additionally, for a non-linear kernel, the intuition of the weights can easily be lost, so always start from first principles if you do this.

Comment: I checked dual_coef_ attribute before, but instead of returning an array of length 5 as we have 5 coefficients(degree = 4) the length of returned array is the same of target array "y" and also all elements are the same as "y". in other words it return target array of training data.

Comment: I add all my code in the question including x and y vector

Comment: Well, actually, firstly the degree parameter is meaningless if you use a non-polynomial kernel. 

degree : float, default=3
Degree of the polynomial kernel. Ignored by other kernels.

Secondly, I think you are conceptualizing what KRR does. I will edit my answer as this is a bit too verbose for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Illustration of how KernelRidge prediction works. Hope it will help someone to understand the model.
[image: Illustration of how KernelRidge prediction works]